# IPython setting text editor

Tags: sublimetext2, ipython

Am trying to set ipython default text editor. Using Ipython 0.13.2   Using the %edit magic I get the following message:

```
No default editor available.
Specify a GUI text editor in the `IPythonWidget.editor` configurable to enable the %edit magic
```

tried looking for it in IPython tried importing IPythonWidget.. no luck

Have checked the following questions:
[Ipython Configuration - Config Classes Overview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15778937/2107677)
also checked the the Overview of Ipython config system. http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html

I can create profiles (using the ipython command line options) and I know where they are have added started files to the **startup** folder in the config directory.

I don't follow how the Configuration classes work at all. Looks like I have to create them?  Should I save them in my ipython configuration startup folder?

Specifically looking to set Sublime Text as editor, but if I can get instructions on any editor, can probably adapt it form there.

Comment: if you're interested in using IPython **in** Sublime Text 2, check out the [`SublimeREPL`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin, available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your profile, edit `ipython_qtconsole_config.py`, you'll find a line `# c.IPythonWidget.editor = ''` uncomment and set the value to the command to launch your editor.

Comment: for some reason I did not have those files in my default profile.   Copied accross from a newly created profile... edited and working... Seeing the files makes the other instructions readable!

Comment: It happens if you've migrated from an older version of IPython that didn't had those files. Happy you got it to work.

Comment: Also,    c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editor = 'vim'     is the setting for ipython console

Answer (score 0):

Do

`$jupyter qtconsole --generate-config`

This will create `jupyter_qtconsole_config.py` in your default jupyter config directory with the option `c.IPythonWidget.editor = ''` commented out

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one. In 2021 the correct name is jupyter_qtconsole_config.py