# Vim editor - zsh shell ipython magic %ed cannot find editor

Tags: vim, ipython, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to use the %ed magic in IPython to use vim as the editor.

- vim is installed
- ipython and ipython qtconsole both work
- zsh is latest as updated with my oh-my-zsh install

I exported my prefernce to zsh

```
$ echo "export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim" >> ~/.zshrc

$ echo "export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim" >> ~/.zshrc
```

However, when I launch IPython and then invoke the %ed magic it fails

```
In [1]: %ed
IPython will make a temporary file named: /tmp/ipython_edit_pu4Yql.py
Editing.../bin/sh: 1: mvim: not found
WARNING: Could not open editor
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using IPython's profile configuration as a means of specifying editor. To do this:

Firstly, generate default configuration files:

```
$ ipython profile create
```

Next, find your `~/.ipython/profile_default/..._config.py` file to edit. For example on IPython 2.4.1,

```
$ vim ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
```

Find the commented-out `.editor` setting, un-comment, and set it to `vim`. For example in IPython 2.4.1, this would look like

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editor = 'vim'
```

You will now find when you start IPython, you can `%ed` and it will call up vim:

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Feb 22 2016, 16:38:42)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: %ed
IPython will make a temporary file named: /tmp/ipython_edit_Tze8Ur/ipython_edit
_gghQG5.py
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
It works
Out[1]: 'print "It works"\n'

In [2]:
```

### Explanation

`man ipython`:

> FILES
>
> IPython uses various configuration files  stored  in  profiles  within
>   IPYTHONDIR.   To  generate  the  default configuration files and start
>   configuring IPython, do 'ipython profile  create',  and  edit  '*_config.py' files located in IPYTHONDIR/profile_default.

`IPYTHONDIR` according to `man ipython`:

> IPYTHONDIR
>
> This  is  the  location where IPython stores all its configuration files.   The  default  is  $HOME/.ipython  if  IPYTHONDIR  is  not defined.
>
> You  can  see  the  computed  value  of  IPYTHONDIR  with `ipython locate`.

Also I mention the version because settings seem different across some versions, for 2.4.1 the setting is called:

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.editor = ...
```

Whereas in the answer given at [IPython setting text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339486/ipython-setting-text-editor), this setting was named differently:

```
c.IPythonWidget.editor = ...
```

Since it seems different between versions, after you generate the default configuration files, check and see how it is written in your IPython version, and act accordingly.