# I get a "could not open editor" warning in IPython even though editor did open

Tags: vim, ipython

When I try to edit a multi-line command in IPython, it opens vim just fine.

I edit my code, but when I write and quit, I get the message

> Editing... WARNING: Could not open editor.

And the edited code does not appear in IPython.

Any idea what this could be? I do have several plugins installed, and can list them if someone thinks a plugin might be the problem.

Comment: What do you see when you execute `echo $EDITOR` in your shell?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809815/vim-editor-zsh-shell-ipython-magic-ed-cannot-find-editor)?

Comment: If your editor terminates with a non-zero exit code, that normally indicates an error, and may be what IPython is picking up.

Comment: zarak, vim actually opens! A post related to actually not finding vim is not relevant.

Comment: And $EDITOR is not set, but vim is the default MacOS editor, and iPython actually finds it fine and runs it. So that can't be the problem.

Comment: Thomas K, I'm sure this is on the right track. Any suggestions on tracking down why vim would exit with a non-zero code?

Comment: Thomas K, I checked, and you got it: vim always exits for me with exit code 1. Now to hunt down why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Thomas K. got the general problem: vim was exiting with an exit code of 1. The cause of **that** was a python flake8 checker that didn't like some formatting as I saved.